# sql subquery and join on one to many table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, subquery, one-to-many

This one is causing me too much head scratching!  Basically, I need to show a list of locations, the current item that is stored there and the person who owns it.  I have created 4 tables and have these populated with data.

Setup: MSSQL 2008

What I am looking for is the "Top(1)" from tbl_locationHistory for the item and owner as there can only ever be one item or one owner at any one time at each location. Bear in mind that tbl_locationHistory could have multiple bits of data, I just need to pull back the latest ID for each one (e.g. the highest ownerID, the highest itemID thats currently available from the history table).

### tbl_location

locID
locName

### tbl_item

itemID
itemName

### tbl_owner

ownerID
ownerName

### tbl_locationHistory

locHistID
locID
itemID
ownerID
dateModified

I tried joining all of these tables together with joins. However I realised that wouldn't work as I wasn't pulling back the top ID for either "owners" or "items" and therefore the data being displayed would be inaccurate.

One things I have thought is that I should break up the history table into two parts: 1 x owner to location and 1 x item to location - however I am at my limit of SQL right now so could do with some pointers in the right direction as not sure which way to go with this.

Therefore I would need assistance even if I have to break up the history table.

**UPDATED 01/11/12**

OK, I am going to paste some code in here.

I am an old school Classic ASP coder.....havent needed to move on yet!  I am using classic asp and MSSQL to create this application. I am also using dreamweaver and therefore want the query to be placed in that so I can use the "bindings" function in DW CS6.

Here was my original query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.pID, p.cliID, p.pNo, p.pName, p.dtCommissioned,     
p.description, ps.plotStatus, pt.plotType, o.oSalutation, o.oFname, o.oSname, man.manName, 
mod.model, sl.width, sl.length, sl.yr
FROM history AS ph INNER JOIN owners AS o ON ph.ownerID   
= o.ownerID INNER JOIN StockList AS sl ON ph.stockID = sl.stkID   
INNER JOIN manufacturers AS man ON sl.make = man.manID 
INNER JOIN models AS mod ON sl.model = mod.cID FULL OUTER   
JOIN plotType AS pt RIGHT OUTER JOIN                       
plots AS p ON pt.plotTypeID = p.plotType LEFT OUTER JOIN                       
plotStatus AS ps ON p.pStatus = ps.plotStatusID ON ph.plotID = p.pID
WHERE (p.cliID = value)
ORDER BY p.pNo
```

Now, when I realised that I wasn't looking in the history table correctly for the highest HistoryID for the "stockID" and also the highest plotHistoryID for "ownerID" I started looking at how I could perform a "subquery" for each ID......this is where I have become stuck.

I have tried  something along the lines of:

```
Select p.pID, p.cliID, p.pNo, p.pName, p.dtCommissioned,     
p.description, ps.plotStatus, pt.plotType, o.oSalutation, o.oFname, o.oSname, man.manName, 
mod.model, sl.width, sl.length, sl.yr
(Select top 1 ph.plotHistoryID, ownerID
FROM History AS ph
order by ph.plotHistoryID desc)
THEN JOINING ETC
THEN DO ANOTHER SUBQUERY FOR THE OWNER ETC
```

However I couldn't get that to work, but I am now beyond my level of SQL in relation to Sub Queries and JOINS.

The Output display will be:

Plot No  |  Plot Name  |  plot type  |  Plot status  |  Current Owner  |  Current Stock

Each of the Plot No's/Names/Type/Status will be populated with data as I need to show them. If the owner\current stock is blank I have an IF statement saying "no owner" or "no stock found".

The user will then be able to then click on a "view" link at the end of the row and view details of the plot/location and will pass the pID to the next page via QueryString.

Does this help?  I am getting a little desparate now! LOL

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, just joining wouldn't be a problem at all. The fact that you sort by dateModified (you are, right?) means that you will get the top of tbl_locationHistory and the other tables will get joined to it properly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` function to help to only get the latest history event per location then use this to join back to owner and item:

```
WITH LocationHistoryExt AS
(   SELECT  LocID, 
            ItemID, 
            OwnerID,
            DateModified,
            [RowNumber] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LocID ORDER BY DateModified DESC)
    FROM    tbl_LocationHistory
)
SELECT  l.LocName,
        i.ItemID,
        o.OwnerName,
        lh.DateModified
FROM    tbl_Location l
        INNER JOIN LocationHistoryExt lh
            ON l.LocID = lh.LocID
            AND RowNumber = 1 -- ONLY LATEST EVENT
        INNER JOIN tbl_Item i
            ON lh.ItemID = i.ItemID
        INNER JOIN tbl_Owner o
            ON o.OwnerID = lh.OwnerID
```

**EDIT - EXPLANATION ADDED**

The top part is a [Common table Expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), in this case it is simply a way of moving the subquery out of the main query, so

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  A, B, C
    FROM    T
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE
```

Is exactly the same as just executing

```
SELECT  A, B, C
FROM    T
```

The [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) within the CTE will assign each history event a row number depending on the `ORDER` and `PARTITION` clauses within it, so given the following sample data in tbl_LocationHistory:

```
locHistID | locID | itemID | ownerID | dateModified
----------+-------+--------+---------+--------------
    1     |   1   |   1    |   1     |  20121001
    2     |   1   |   4    |   2     |  20121002
    3     |   1   |   3    |   1     |  20121003  <-- LATEST FOR LocID 1
    4     |   2   |   5    |   2     |  20121002
    5     |   2   |   1    |   2     |  20121004
    6     |   2   |   2    |   3     |  20121005  <-- LATEST FOR LocID 2
```

I have assumed what you are trying to do is retrieve the latest row for each location ID, and get the itemID and OwnerID associated with that row, so deconstructing the `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LocID ORDER BY DateModified DESC);
```

This will allocate each row in your data a row number, starting again at 1 for each `LocID` (`PARITION BY locID`), it will begin numbering at 1 from the record with the Latest Modified date (`ORDER BY DateModified DESC`). Applying this to the sample data you would get:

```
locHistID | locID | itemID | ownerID | dateModified | RowNumber
----------+-------+--------+---------+--------------+---------------
    1     |   1   |   1    |   1     |  20121001    | 3
    2     |   1   |   4    |   2     |  20121002    | 2
    3     |   1   |   3    |   1     |  20121003    | 1
    4     |   2   |   5    |   2     |  20121002    | 3
    5     |   2   |   1    |   2     |  20121004    | 2
    6     |   2   |   2    |   3     |  20121005    | 1
```

This is what is retrived in the CTE in my query, then when I have joined to it I've added that `RowNumber = 1`, this means only the latest rows are returned

```
FROM    tbl_Location l
        INNER JOIN LocationHistoryExt lh
            ON l.LocID = lh.LocID
            AND RowNumber = 1 -- ONLY LATEST EVENT


locHistID | locID | itemID | ownerID | dateModified | RowNumber
----------+-------+--------+---------+--------------+---------------
    3     |   1   |   3    |   1     |  20121003    | 1
    6     |   2   |   2    |   3     |  20121005    | 1
```

The remainder is just normal joining to get the appropriate Location, Owner and Item from the above 2 rows.

I hope this makes more sense now. If not let me know and I will trying and explain any other bits.

**EDIT 2 - ACCOUNTING FOR NULL FIELDS**

I've changed the order of the select slightly and changed `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`, but the principal is still the same:

```
WITH LocationHistoryExt AS
(   SELECT  LocID, 
            ItemID, 
            OwnerID,
            DateModified,
            [RowNumber] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LocID ORDER BY DateModified DESC)
    FROM    tbl_LocationHistory
)
SELECT  [LocationName] = COALESCE(l.LocName, 'No Location'),
        [ItemName] = COALESCE(i.ItemName, 'No Item'),
        [OwnerName] = COALESCE(o.OwnerName, 'No Owner'),
        lh.DateModified
FROM    LocationHistoryExt lh
        LEFT JOIN tbl_Location l
            ON l.LocID = lh.LocID
        LEFT JOIN tbl_Item i
            ON lh.ItemID = i.ItemID
        LEFT JOIN tbl_Owner o
            ON o.OwnerID = lh.OwnerID
WHERE   RowNumber = 1 -- ONLY LATEST EVENT
```

Comment: Hi Gareth. Thanks for the comment, but this doesn't help me much......I don't understand what you have written does!?! Sorry, but that is my level of coding ability.  I am building a web application, but for the most part queries are quite simple, with standard sub-queries.  Now I am looking pulling it all together and I feel a little confused.  I need to be able to select * from locations, show the current item at that location and the current owner of the item.....these later 2 bindings would be in the history table as ID's.....does that help you any further?  Or anyone else for that matter?

Comment: Right, I have your query working which is great news!  However as I understand it and from what I can see as the result, it only pulls back rows where everything matches. That is great for one report, but I would like to also show where items are empty and no owner applied.....I have 0 (zero's) for empty fields rather than NULL values in the history table if that helps you in anyway. I think with a little bit more help I should be there!  For the fields that come back as zero's I will replace those with "no owner" and "no stock" in the GUI with IF statements etc.

Comment: @NickGreen further edited answer which will hopefully solve the issue.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do and I really appreciate the detailed help. However this seems to return just one row of data. SQL did error on a conversion when I ran it - i.ItemName is not something I hold. Moreover it is an ID that I reference from another two tables....one for make and one for model.....does that throw any light on things?

Comment: sorry, forgot to put your name in the comment above. Thanks in advance, Nick

Comment: Can you edit the question to show some sample data, the output you are expecting, and the output you are getting please? This should give me an idea of the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the question with more detail.  Basically, it is my original query prior to realising that I hadn't checked the history table for the highest historyID for both the "ownerID" or "stockID".